# hide add this sharing tool default icons

Tags: javascript, css, addthis

Does anyone know how I hide the defualt icons that the add this (addthis.com) sharing widget uses by default to replace with my own icons?

The code I am using is below, the add this widget brings in icons but I want to use my main_icons.gif. Thanks in advance.

```
<style type="text/css">
.share strong { line-height:17px; }
.share strong, .share a { float:left; display:inline; font-weight:normal; }
.share a { width:17px; height:17px; background:transparent url(main_icons.gif) no-repeat 0px -1772px; margin-left:7px; text-indent:-9999px; }
.share a.btn_twitter { background-position:-24px -1772px; }
.share a.btn_share { background-position:-47px -1772px; }
</style>

<div class="share addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<strong>Share this:</strong>
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" href="">Share with Facebook</a>
<a class="btn_twitter addthis_button_twitter" href="">Share with Twitter</a>
    <a class="btn_share addthis_button_compact" href="">Share</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_config = {
    "data_track_addressbar":true,
    "services_exclude":'facebook,twitter',
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=myusername"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the answer here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#.T-zBZ_VRL90

You just but an image tag with the src of your custom image in your a tag... e.g.

```
<a class="addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php"><img src="customButton.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Share" /></a>
```